# Apple Watch Integration for Authenticating Prompts in Swift/Objective-C Apps

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, apple-watch, watchos

I'm trying to figure out how to authenticate a prompt (in macOS), via an Apple Watch, for an application. Something similar to the behavior of Finder when authenticating while the "Use your Apple Watch to unlock this Mac" setting is toggled.

I have been trying to figure out how to do this for a bit and can't find any documentation from Apple, or any articles regarding this.

Short code examples and API documentation is helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the [Local Authentication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/) framework. While it seems to be focused primarily on iOS, you will find that one of the [LAPolicy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lapolicy) options is `deviceAuthenticationWithWatch`. You could also use `deviceAuthenticationWithWatchOrBiometrics` if you want to support Touch ID if the Mac has it, or use `deviceOwnerAuthentication` to also allow the system password. Note that if you use `deviceOwnerAuthentication` it will use the password for the computer, not the password for your app

There are first steps on [the Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/logging_a_user_into_your_app_with_face_id_or_touch_id). Hope this helps!